# How to remove white space like margin between two iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to make two iframes of width 50% in same line! But instead second frame goes below first frame.

Answer (score 0):

These two iframes have a whitespace between them, that's why they don't fit on a single line. The solution is to put the markup for these two iframes on a single line. There are muliple ways to fix this, please take a look at this - [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```css
iframe {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#iframe-two {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" id="iframe-one"></iframe><iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" id="iframe-two"></iframe>
```